# Using VBA for Excel i want to make the text bold

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macro to find all the words written a column in another excel & make them bold.

For EX: I have Words like new, grow, etc written in a column B of Excel an the macro has to Find theses words individually in another excel & make them bold and change the Background of the cell to Red Color.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes Jmax: I tried a Macro, But in it i either need to give a Input Box or a I need to provide a Individual word as the macro does not go automatically go on the next below cell of the column.

Comment: Are the words in cells by themselves or part of longer text?

Comment: @Tim: They are a part of some Words in a sentence Example Reserve is the word which is a part of a Sentence "We need to Keep a XX Amount of Reserve wit us.: & I want the Whole Sentence or i would say the CEll to be Bold.

Comment: What about "preserve"? Would that be highlighted?  How is the other Excel file to be selected? Is it already open?  You can use the .Find() method of the Range object to do what you want.  See here http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=780 for an example.  Try it out.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have written codes which will open the file where we are searching, also the above ;ink is partially usefull as i want a macro which will take the Cell Values as reference for searching  & not the input box to Bold the cell also i want the Word to be bold in the cell where the word is present.

Comment: Hey Tim, Can i get a way where the macro can fill all the Cells which contain the Word we have mentioned in a cell in a different Excel?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look into conditionnal formatting.

Assume for example you have the values you want to look for in column B, and you want to highlight all values in a range, say, `D4:F15`.

Select the range `D4:F15`, make a new formatting rule and choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Enter `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(D4;$B:$B))` as formula, and make the format as you wish. Note that `D4` in the formula has to be the first cell of the range.

If you don't need more than that, the benefit is that you don't need a macro at all, and the formatting can be done in real time too.

Comment: Joubarc: I Want a Macro which will help me & i want to Bold the word in a different Sheet not in the sheet & also don't want a persons time being used in it.

Comment: The 'different sheet' part is easily solved, just replace `$B:$B` by the proper reference to another sheet. If you really want a macro, well, this is indeed not what you want, but I thought it might be interesting as a different approach to the problem at hand. What puzzles me though is you "don't want a persons time being used in it" - I'm not sure I understand that. Whose time? yours? ours? As JMax said, what did you try so far?

Comment: Joubarc: I mean i don't want a persons (user of Macro) to take time & put formula to all the fields as we have too many excels to do the task, in which the just the excel will change but the Words remain the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification - you may want to explicit that in the question as well

Comment: Ooh, Sorry for it. Next Question i will make sure of it, as i am new to the interface.

Comment: It seems you cannot use a reference to another sheet in a formatting formula, so my plan wouldn't work in your case anyway. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Joubarc: your solution is still a very good one. You **can** use a reference to another sheet in a Conditional Formatting by using [Named Range](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/named.htm). Btw, i +1 your solution :) and i don't think i will give a vba answer

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the named range workaround (well, I didn't know a workaround was needed in the first place).

Comment: Is it possible to build macro for my Request?