# How to make text appear bold using VBA Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to send few mails containing employee information as given below.

**First Name:** ABC 
**Last Name:** DEF
**Employee ID:** 0000000

what I've done is as follows

```
olmailitem.body = "First Name: " & Cells(cell.row, "D").Value & vbNewLine & "Last Name: " _
& Cells(cell.row, "E").Value & vbNewLine & "Employee ID: " & Cells(cell.row, "F").Value & vbNewLine
```

Now, my question is how do I print `First Name`, `Last Name`, and `Employee ID` as given above in Bold?

Comment: Have you tried `.HTMLBody` e.g. `olmailitem.HTMLbody = "<b>First Name: </b>" & Cells(cell.row, "D").Value & ... `?

Comment: Only these three words should come in bold otherwise the full mail contains about 15-20 lines so if I use .HTMLBody then it will be come a very complex code.

Answer (score 0):

As [Joubarc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316256/using-vba-for-excel-i-want-to-make-the-text-bold) said

You may want to have a look into conditionnal formatting.

Assume for example you have the values you want to look for in column B, and you want to highlight all values in a range, say, D4:F15.

Select the range D4:F15, make a new formatting rule and choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Enter =ISNUMBER(MATCH(D4;$B:$B)) as formula, and make the format as you wish. Note that D4 in the formula has to be the first cell of the range.

If you don't need more than that, the benefit is that you don't need a macro at all, and the formatting can be done in real time too.

Comment: That's the way to highlight values in a range of cells. I want to send out a mail and make some words bold in that mail. It would be a mail containing 15-20 lines and only these three words should come in bold so I can't .HTMLBody because that will make it a lot more complex. Is there any way to selectively format a word using macro when sending a mail?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making HTMLBody more complicated than it really is. If you don't include any html tags, HTMLBody and Body are almost the same.

Whenever I'm concatenating a bunch of strings, I like to put them in arrays, then use Join to build the string. It's more efficient, but even for small procedures I think it just looks cleaner. In the below example, I put all of the employee stuff into an array called aFirstLine() then join that with a space in between all of the elements.  Then I put that plus all the other lines in an array called aBody() which I join separating the elements with an HTML line break.

Here's the example.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim aFirstLine(1 To 6) As String
    Dim aBody(1 To 20) As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'Put all the employee pieces in an array with html codes
    aFirstLine(1) = "<b>First Name:</b>"
    aFirstLine(2) = "ABC"
    aFirstLine(3) = "<b>Last Name:</b>"
    aFirstLine(4) = "DEF"
    aFirstLine(5) = "<b>Employee ID</b>:"
    aFirstLine(6) = "0000000"

    'join the employee stuff into one string
    aBody(1) = Join(aFirstLine, Space(1))
    'this will create a blank line
    aBody(2) = "&nbsp;"
    'Create all the other lines
    For i = 3 To 20
        aBody(i) = "This is line " & i
    Next i

    'join the body array using the html line break as a separator
    With olMail
        .HTMLBody = Join(aBody, "<br />")
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that only the first line has html tags. All the other lines are concatenated exactly the same whether I use Body or HTML Body.